# Table of contents for a single publishing page's sections

Tags: 2010, publishing-site

Is it possible to do a table of contents (TOC) for the sections of a page rather than the sites in a site collection for SharePoint 2010?

I'm thinking of the TOC on Wikipedia that appears at the top of longer pages and has links to sections within that page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can use the HTML Hyperlink Bookmark Tag. By using the tag you can create your own TOC with links to sections within the page.
Here is a link to some explanation and example: 
http://www.ezineasp.net/Samples/HTML/HTML-Basics/HTML-Hyperlink-Bookmark-Tag/Default.aspx

This can be used in e.g. a CEWP.

Comment: Thanks, Anita. I found an automated solution using jQuery: http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/css/jquery-plugin-smooth-scrolling/comment-page-1/#comment-96225 I had to modify the JS file for it to detect id being undefined but it works well. It automatically generates a TOC for all H1, H2, H3 tags within the main content area of the page layout. I've added a custom True/False dropdown to the page layout to let the user enable/disable the TOC for pages. There's a display:none DIV on the page, floated left of the page heading. If the field is set to True, it shows the DIV and injects the TOC into it.

Comment: Alex, That looks great! Thanks for keeping me posted.

Answer (score 1):

Old question I know , but I Stumpled accross this:

http://devmoss.wordpress.com/2011/05/06/jquery-page-toc/